# Convert String (with other string in) in Date Object - Python

Tags: python, string, date, object, french

I'm trying to convert this French string : **'20 avril 2018 - Arrivée définitive'** as a Date Object.

```
Jour = ['20 avril 2018 - Arrivée définitive', '21 septembre 2018 - Arrivée définitive', '1 décembre 2019 - Arrivée définitive']
```

I tried :

```
import dateparser # $ pip install dateparser

for date_string in Jour:
    print(dateparser.parse(date_string).date())
```

But I have this error :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'date'
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

I'm hoping that this will help someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read in [documentation](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) The `parse` function returns `datetime representing parsed date if successful, else returns None` so while looping, the parse function returned `None` of which you tried to use `date` function causing an error.

I am not sure if it would help but If you check in console:

```
>>> import dateparser
>>> dateparser.parse("20 avril 2018 - Arrivée définitive")
>>> dateparser.parse("21 septembre 2018 - Arrivée définitive")
>>> dateparser.parse("21 septembre 2018")
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 21, 0, 0)
>>>
```

So string "21 septembre 2018" parses well but "21 septembre 2018 - Arrivée définitive" parses as `None` (nothing printed means `None` in this case)

Comment: Thank you mucka ! The problems is, to solve this you can just find and replace the " - Arrivée définitive" by space but on a very long list of more than 5 million elements like I have, you just have to start again a new regex to replace everything. I solve it like that. The thing is I just wanted it to work without having to do that. Thank you for everything.